# How to check first word of string is in Capital in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to check first word of string is in Capital or not. How can we check that in php.

Let say string is :

HELLO how are you.

now in that case i want to check HELLO is in Caps or not. How can we check that in PHP.

Comment: Pseudo-solution: 1) extract first word; 2) capitalize it; 3) compare. Shouldn't be too hard to find how each step is done.

Comment: Regex will be the solution I think. on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) you can check it and learn a bit about it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With a regular expression you can check that

```
<?php

$regex = '/^[A-Z]*\s/m'; //Regular expression
$str = 'HELLO how are you.';

if(preg_match($regex, $str)) {
    echo 'First word is all capital';
} else {
    echo 'First word is not capital';   
}
```

The next time you need help try to put some code to view your effort.

Comment: Using `^([A-Z]+)` as regex is maybe better for if you whant to use the returned word. The white space at the end of the word is then also trimmed of

Comment: what if i want to check for second word the same thing then what need to be changed ??

Comment: This doesn't really cover all the cases: https://3v4l.org/I1jIe A word boundary might be a better choice than whitespace. @NamitSingh That completely changes the question. You might want to consider writing a new one or editing your current question to present both cases (or, as I have the feeling you'll ask about the third word after that, a more generic case of what you need).

Comment: Ok but what i have did i have trim and got the second word i.e now i have HELLO now i have to check this is capital or not ?